# How to switch betwen click and mouseenter methods?

Tags: jquery, button, click, switch-statement, mouseenter

I have two buttons:

```
<button id="Ck">Click</button>
<button id="Me">Mouseenter</button>
```

I want to give the user chance to choose how to open my jQuery animated menus (on click or on mouseenter), by clicking one of this two buttons.

Is there any way to switch betwen these methods? And what I have to do to keep these chooses even when the page is refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily.

First, give the buttons a class:

```
<button id="Ck" class="ClickMouseenter">Click</button>
<button id="Me" class="ClickMouseenter">Click</button>
```

Then check the id when the button is clicked, and assign appropriately:

```
$('.ClickMouseenter').on('click',function(){
    var id = this.id,
        $menu = $('#MenuExample');

    $menu.off();
    if(id==='Ck'){
        $menu.on('click',function(){
             // click magic;
        });
    } else {
        $menu.on('mouseenter',function(){
            // mouseenter magic;
        });
    }
});
```

Or if they perform the same function just with different handlers:

```
// yay for faster code processing!
$('.ClickMouseenter').on('click',function(){
    var id = this.id,
        action = (id==='Ck' ? 'click' : 'mouseenter');

    $('#MenuExample').off().on(action,function(){
        // action magic;
    });
});
```

The `.off()` removes the assignment that was existing (`click` or `mouseenter`), and then a new `.on()` handler is applied depending on the `id` of the `button` you clicked.

In regards to keeping these settings upon page refresh ... my first inclination is using `sessionStorage` (note: this will only work on IE8 and above; if you're coding for IE6 or IE7, you're out of luck). Create a function from the event which includes `sessionStorage` assignment:

```
function setMenu(action){
    $('#MenuExample').off().on(action,function(){
        // action magic;
    });
    sessionStorage.menuType = action;
}

$('.ClickMouseenter').on('click',function(){
    var id = this.id,
        action = (id==='Ck' ? 'click' : 'mouseenter');

    setMenu(action);
});
```

And now you can call it on page load to reassign the choice if necessary, with a default fallback:

```
if(sessionStorage.length > 0){
    setMenu(sessionStorage.menuType);
} else {
    setMenu('mouseenter');
}
```

This is obviously an oversimplified version, but should give an idea to start with.

Comment: Can you take a look at my answer? Is down here! I need some help!

Comment: have u tried my answer? or did u only try the other answer? because the key to what you're talking about is `.off()`, which is included in my answer.

Comment: I tryed it. But I am a beginer. It's too complicated for me. I can't understand anything. I don't deny your knowledge, but it's just too complicate for me. Why don't you help me with a fiddle? It would be much better than a comment. Comments don't really help me, because english is not my forte. Modify this feddle please: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VMDBN/2/)

Comment: updated your jsFiddle, with as many explanatory comments as I could => http://jsfiddle.net/VMDBN/6/. also, included the thing to make localStorage work, and made the existing functions u had much more efficient by use of caching and `$(this)`.

Comment: an even more improved version, consolidating the animation you run into a single function (since its the exact same, just different speeds) => http://jsfiddle.net/VMDBN/8/

Comment: The localStorage works awesome! Thanks! I really appreciate it!

Comment: honestly, i really hope you glean more from my jsFiddle than the localStorage working. the code you had works, but it was highly inefficient, and i put a lot of effort into making it as efficient as possible with explanations as to why. i realize you are a beginner, but you should be learning best practices, not just "good enough to work" practices.

Answer (score 0):

You would just set up the menu based on whichever was clicked:

```
function SetupClick() {
  // Setup click functionality here
}

function SetupMouseover() {
  // Setup mouseover functionality here
}

$('#Ck').click(function() {
  SetupClick();
  // Optionally, save choice
  localStorage['userchoice'] = 'click';
});
$('#Me').click(function() {
  SetupMouseover();
  // Optionally, save choice
  localStorage['userchoice'] = 'mouseover';
});
```

You could save the choices serverside, or you could use [HTML5 Local Storage](http://php-html.net/tutorials/html5-local-storage-guide/), but it isn't supported in older browsers.  If you saved the choice, you would have to setup the function on document load:

```
$(document).load(function() {
  if (localStorage && localStorage["userchoice") {
    if (localStorage["userchoice"] == 'click') {
      SetupClick();
    }
    else if (localStorage["userChoice"] == 'mouseover') {
      SetupMouseover();
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a link to your updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMDBN/5/).  I cleaned up the code a little and added a call to `$('#Wp').off();` to reset the events so both wouldn't happen.

Comment: It works but if I click "Click" button and "Mouseover" second, animation run on mouseenter, but on click too. How to disable the other choice?

Comment: I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMDBN/5/).  You can disable the other choice by calling `$('#Wp').off();`